# Saving password in Chrome breaks all postbacks on my page

Tags: asp.net

Something absolutely bizarre began occurring in my ASP 4 application about a month ago with the advent of one of the later releases of Chrome 26, and has continued to be an issue in all builds of Chrome 27 to date. One of my co-workers reported that when he used this application via Chrome, many of the buttons (it turns out they were all the postbacks on the page) stopped working. I began testing older versions of the app to see if I could pinpoint where I might have gone wrong and it turns out that ALL previous builds were now exhibiting the same behavior. We were able to find a PC whose Chrome browser had not been automatically updated and behold, we could not replicate the issue on there!

When this state occurs, all postback buttons and links become completely dead. They visually behave as if they've been clicked but nothing happens behind the scenes. No Javascript calls, nothing! It's as if the buttons are simply disabled in the eyes of Chrome.

This week, I finally figured out the key to make the issue occur and stop. When I clear saved passwords from Chrome, postbacks are restored. As long as I don't allow Chrome to re-save my password, the application and all its postbacks work fine. As soon as I save the password again, I'm dead in the water within the next few clicks (yes, the postbacks DO continue working for a short time).

To make things even more bizarre, traditional hyperlinks and non-doPostBack JavaScript onclick's are not affected by this issue.

Any thoughts on what kind of code in my app could be causing this behavior? I'm not even sure where to begin!

Comment: Are you sure it's saved passwords and not [Autofill forms](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142893?hl=en)? I've seen the latter feature break many forms with hidden inputs that are used by JavaScript, mainly because the filling doesn't fire events. If you can create a small, static (just HTML and inline JS) page that reproduces the issue, you might be able to file a bug with Chome (if it doesn't exist yet). See also [Disable Firefox's Auto-fill](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487970/) and [Chrome autofill is overlapping label text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823330/).

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I had the app in a non-working state just a few moments ago, cleared nothing except the "Saved passwords" (did not clear Autofill form data) and the form is posting again.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information CodeCaster. I will look into that.

Comment: I just tried disabling Autofill and the problem still occurs whenever I allow Chrome to save my password.

Comment: OK, that's weird. I'm not that deep into DOM debugging so I don't know _how_, but perhaps you can try to see what changes in the DOM with and without saved passwords. Maybe you can just hit F12 in both situations, copy the `html` node and compare the results in a tool like Notepad++.

Comment: Tried that long ago. :) The markup is identical. I do think you're on to something, though, with the form data. I have a couple modal popup forms on the page and am unable to expose those when this issue occurs. I think it's probably about time that I expose those by default so I can see what, if anything, Chrome is trying to do with them when the password is saved.

Comment: I don't mean the markup (View Source), but the actual in-memory representation of your page (the DOM, viewable through F12). Sorry if you did mean that. Good luck anyway. :)

Comment: Sounds like there is an event handler that is throwing a Javscript exception and halting execution before doPostBack gets to do its work. If you hit F12/console tab, the errors ought to appear there.